# Checkbox before label text in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have the following function:

```
addCheckbox: function (name, parent, value, text) {
    var div = jQuery("#" + parent);
    var input = jQuery(document.createElement('input')).attr({
        id: "cbid_" + value,
        name: name,
        value: value,
        type: 'checkbox'
    });
    var label = jQuery("<label>").text(text);

    input.appendTo(label);
    div.append(label);
},
```

Now, this works, but it produces the following result:

[image: Text comes before checkbox]

I want to add the checkbox *before* the label so it would look like `[x] Document Files`. Is there a way to do this without using `html()`?

Comment: use prepend http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/):

```
var label = jQuery("<label>").text(text);

input.prependTo(label); // <=== Here
div.append(label);
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can go CSS only: using a property similar to `float: left` on the `<input>` elements, or `float: right` on the `<label>` elements.